# Why do low energy particles ionise more than high energy particles when traveling through matter?

Tags: particle-physics, ionization-energy

Regarding the Bethe Bloch formula, low energy particles ionise more than high energy particles as you can see in the plot.

[image: Plot of Bethe Bloch formula]

I would be interested in a physical explanation of that since it seems intuitive to assume that high energy particles ionise more.

Comment: Your figure is Figure 34.2 in the [Particle Data Group's Review of Particle Physics](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/reviews/contents_sports.html), the section [Passage of Particles Through Matter](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/reviews/rpp2020-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf) (pdf link). Have you tried reading that part of the review? In particular compare to Figure 34.1, which has a bigger range of $\beta\gamma$ for just one material. The key to understanding the shape of this curve is understanding the maximum energy that can be lost per collision, $W_\text{max}$ in the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph shows $\frac{dE}{dx}$ of an ionizing particle,
i.e. its energy loss *per length*.
When a fast particle flies through matter,
it stays only a short time in the vicinity of any atom,
and therefore has little chance to transfer part of
its energy to the atom and kicking out an electron.
A slower particle on the other hand, stays a longer time
near any atom and therefore feels the electric field
of its constituents (electrons and nucleus) for longer
time, thus transfering more energy to it.

You find this reasoning in a more quantitative way
in every derivation of the [Bethe-Bloch formula](https://www.dkfz.de/en/medizinische-physik-radioonkologie/Teaching/02_Physics_Charged_Particle_Therapy_PM.pdf),
and also in the derivation of its non-relativistic
counterpart (the classical Bohr formula).
See for example [DKFZ - Physics of Charged Particle Therapy](https://www.dkfz.de/en/medizinische-physik-radioonkologie/Teaching/02_Physics_Charged_Particle_Therapy_PM.pdf)
(especially page 15):

[image]

Comment: That does make sense but wouldn't it be more likely for a fast particle to kick an electron out every time  it hits an atom just due to it's high kinetic energy. In that scenario the high energy particle would ionise more if the cross section is high enough. Please correct me if I assumed wrong.

Comment: @gamma See the amendment in my updated answer.